# Pointers and Arrays c++

Tags: arrays, pointers, dynamic

In my for loop how is the pointer being incremented without actually being incremented? Also how can I use the pointer later without resetting its value to the beginning of the array?

#include 
    using namespace std;

```
void main()
{
    double *Sales;
    int numDays;
    double sum = 0;
    double avg;
    cout << "Enter the number of days of sales";
    cin >> numDays;
    Sales = new double[numDays];

    for (int i = 0; i <= numDays; i++)
    {
        cin >> *Sales;
        sum = sum + *Sales;
    }

    delete[] Sales;
    avg = sum / (numDays + 1);
    cout << sum << endl;
    cout << avg << endl;
}
```

Comment: Several issues: Your loop should only be until i<numDays - You allocated an array of doubles and assign the pointer to the first element to Sales. That's what the Sales = new....line does. So all you're doing in the loop is writing a value to the first element of the Sales array over and over. Why even use an array?

Comment: actually its filling the entire array.Although logically the array should be only overwriting  the first element. thats my question why is it doing so.Also this program is strictly for learning purposes.